# .IllegalArgumentException: at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags (PendingIntent.java:375)

Tags: java

PendingIntent getGraphPendingIntent() {
// Let the configure Button show the Log

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(this, getPackageName() + ".view.MainActivity"));

    intent.putExtra("PAGE", "graph");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    PendingIntent startLW = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0 );
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    return startLW;

}
```